# Installing dot2texi step by step under Windows

Tags: dot2texi

I used this User's guide

https://dot2tex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I download python-2.7.14.msi from https://docs.python.org/2.7/installing/index.html

I install python-2.7.14.msi

Add

`;C:\python25`

in Systemsteuerung>System>Erweiterte Systemeinstellung>Umgebungsvariablen>Systemvariablen>Path.

I download pyparsing-2.2.0.win32-py2.7 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyparsing/files/pyparsing/pyparsing-2.2.0/pyparsing-2.2.0.win32-py2.7.exe/download

I installed pyparsing-2.2.0.win32-py2.7

I download dot2tex-2.9.0.zip

I unzip dot2tex-2.9.0.zip to C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\dot2tex-2.9.0

I try to use pip, this should work because I use the version 2.7.14 of python:

https://dot2tex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_guide.html#using-pip-or-easy-install

I start python (command line)

C:\Python27\python.exe starts

I type in "pip install dot2tex"
It shows:

```
>>> pip install dot2tex   
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install dot2tex
              ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What do I do wrong?

I start IDLE (Python GUI)

It shows:

"Python 2.7.14 Shell"

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> LE
```

I load with

File>open...>Desktop>dot2tex-2.9.0>setup.py

the setupfile of dot2tex-2.9.0

I do "Run>Run Module"

It shows

```
========== RESTART: C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\dot2tex-2.9.0\setup.py ==========
>>>
```

I download graphviz-2.38.msi from https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html

I install graphviz-2.38.msi

I add

`;C:\Program Files\Graphviz2.38\bin`

in Systemsteuerung>System>Erweiterte Systemeinstellung>Umgebungsvariablen>Systemvariablen>Path.

I open Command Promt

I type "D:>dot2tex a.dot"

It comes that the command "dot2tex" was not found.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One step at a time

you installed python 2.7 but say you added add ;c:\python25
I would expect different as you later show ;c:\python27

So check with> `where /r \ python2.7` (if it dos not work with `python2.7` then try just `python` but you should have both for later commands)
and ensure path above = the folder as given back
ALSO add scripts so in your case it may be

```
set path= c:\python27;c:\python27\scripts;%path%
```

or permanently add both to the system environment

Old question asked for dot2tex-2.9.0 but that was from 2014 the current is dot2tex-2.11.3.tar.gz  which pip will download and install for you

Pip is usually called through Python so having added python to your path first update pip

```
>Python2.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip  

>Python2.7 -m pip install dot2tex
```

you should see

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st,
>   2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python
>   2.7. Collecting dot2tex   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ca/9e/26e11dfd9762eda401181b4cf388de5421d4ccfdddef0ddc1a8c9256e072/dot2tex-2.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting pyparsing (from dot2tex)   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/0a/001be530836743d8be6c2d85069f46fecf84ac6c18c7f5fb8125ee11d854/pyparsing-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   (61kB)
>       100% |################################| 71kB 508kB/s Installing collected packages: pyparsing, dot2tex   The script dot2tex.exe is
>   installed in 'c:\python27\Scripts' Successfully installed
>   dot2tex-2.11.3 pyparsing-2.3.1

Now check with

```
D:>dot2tex --version
Dot2tex version 2.11.3
```